# Why TRY_PARSE its so slow?

Tags: sql-server, performance, datetime, parsing

I have this query that basically returns (right now) only 10 rows as results:

```
select *
FROM Table1 as o
inner join Table2 as t on t.Field1 = o.Field2
where Code = 123456 and t.FakeData is not null
```

Now, if I want to parse the field FakeData (which, unfortunately, can contain different types of data, from DateTime to Surname/etc; i.e. nvarchar(70)), for data show and/or filtering:

```
select *, TRY_PARSE(t.FakeData as date USING 'en-GB') as RealDate
FROM Table1 as o
inner join Table2 as t on t.Field1 = o.Field2
where Code = 123456 and t.FakeData is not null
```

It takes x10 the query to be executed.

Where am I wrong? How can I speed up?

I can't edit the database, I'm just a customer which read data.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: A column that contains different types of data suggests a schema design flaw and you may pay a penalty in queries.

Comment: which table contains `code` used in the where clause? (tip: always include the alias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TSQL documentation for [`TRY_PARSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) makes the following observation:

> Keep in mind that there is a certain performance overhead in parsing the string value.

NB: I am assuming your typical date format would be dd/mm/yyyy.

The following is something of a shot-in-the-dark that might help. By progressively assessing the `nvarchar` column if it is a candidate as a date it is possible to reduce the number of uses of that function. Note that a data point established in one apply can then be referenced in a subsequent apply:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   FakeData NVARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(FakeData) VALUES (N'oiwsuhd ouhw dcouhw oduch woidhc owihdc oiwhd cowihc');
INSERT INTO mytable(FakeData) VALUES (N'9603200-0297r2-0--824');
INSERT INTO mytable(FakeData) VALUES (N'12/03/1967');
INSERT INTO mytable(FakeData) VALUES (N'12/3/2012');
INSERT INTO mytable(FakeData) VALUES (N'3/3/1812');
INSERT INTO mytable(FakeData) VALUES (N'ohsw dciuh iuh pswiuh piwsuh cpiuwhs dcpiuhws ipdcu wsiu');

select
      t.FakeData, oa3.RealDate
from mytable as t
outer apply (
    select len(FakeData) as fd_len
    ) oa1
outer apply (
    select case when oa1.fd_len > 10 then 0
                when len(replace(FakeData,'/','')) + 2 = oa1.fd_len then 1
                else 0
           end as is_candidate
    ) oa2
outer apply (
    select case when oa2.is_candidate = 1 then TRY_PARSE(t.FakeData as date USING 'en-GB') end as RealDate
    ) oa3
```

| FakeData | RealDate |
| --- | --- |
| oiwsuhd ouhw dcouhw oduch woidhc owihdc oiwhd cowihc | *null* |
| 9603200-0297r2-0--824 | *null* |
| 12/03/1967 | 1967-03-12 |
| 12/3/2012 | 2012-03-12 |
| 3/3/1812 | 1812-03-03 |
| ohsw dciuh iuh pswiuh piwsuh cpiuwhs dcpiuhws ipdcu wsiu | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ebce813c49a584948e5d4542c3b5779e)*

Comment: Code shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: Really? I was not aware that markdown was subject to such inflexibility. Notable also it is that the markdown is supplied by db-fiddle.

Comment: `try_parse` on 10 rows is negligible. The source of the problem should be that it's performed on the entire table and only the wanted 10 rows are then kept, which is a problem not really caused by `try_parse`.

Comment: Yes. Exactly why I proposed a way to reduce the number of calls but without tests of course I cannot guarantee an improvement.